# Prove convexity of three similar sets

Tags: convex-optimization, proof-explanation

given the following 3 sets:

$ \{ (x,y,z): x \ge y^2 + z^2, z>0 \} $

$ \{ (x,y,z): x^2 \ge y^2 + z^2, y>0 \} $

$ \{ (x,y,z): x^2 \ge y^2 + z^2, x>0 \} $

The first set is convex because it is a sum of convex set.

Why is the second set not convex? I thought it is also a convex sum: $y^2+z^2-x^2$? And why is in example 3: $-x^2+y^2+z^2$ again a convex sum?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: For set #2, $(-1,1,0)$ belongs and $(1,1,0)$ belongs but convex combination $(0,1,0)$ doesn't belong. Also observe that $-x^2$ isn't convex, and $y^2  + z^2 - x^2$ isn't convex.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Set 3 is convex (if the solution of the book/script is right)

Comment: What does it mean to be "a sum of a convex set"? This is not a well-posed phrase. (Yes, you can add sets, but that's not what you're talking about.)

Answer (score 0):

For set #2: 
$(−1,1,0)$ belongs and $(1,1,0)$ belongs but convex combination $(0,1,0)$ doesn't belong. Note that $-x^2$ isn't a convex function and $y^2+z^2-x^2$ is likewise not convex.

For set #3:
If $x > 0$ then:
$$ x^2 \geq y^2 + z^2 \Leftrightarrow 0 \geq \sqrt{y^2 +z^2} - x $$
Observe $f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{y^2+z^2} - x$ is a convex function since it's the sum of a convex function (2-norm of (x,y)) and an affine function ($-x$). The [sub-level set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set#Sublevel_and_superlevel_sets) of a convex function is a convex set.